# BFS implementation in C throwing segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, breadth-first-search

This is a BFS program in c. In the function "bfs(struct Graph *G, int v)" after entering into the loop  "while(Q!=NULL)" there is only one iteration happening in the loop(means it is printing only adjascent edges of the first vertices entered as a input)... next time when it checks while(Q!=NULL) it is throwing segmentation fault(when next vertices is entered as input).

In the first example in output:
when i am entering as 0(as first vertices) and 1 (as its edge) ,it is printing only that ... when it going for the next input 1(as first vertices) and 2 (as its edge) it is throwing segmentation fault

similarly for the second example in output:
when i am entering as 0(as first vertices) and 1 and 2(as its edge) ,it is printing only that , when i am entering next vertices its throwing seg fault...

Mainly i guess its not looping inside while(Q!=NULL).

can anyone help me resolving this??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX 25

struct Queue
{
   int data;
   struct Queue *next;
};

struct node
{
  int verticenum;
  struct node *next;
};

struct list
{
 struct node *head;
};

struct Graph
{
  int V;
  int E;
  struct list *Adj;
};


struct Queue* Enqueue(struct Queue* head,int data)
{
   struct Queue* p=malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
   struct Queue* curr=head;
   p->data=data;
   if(head==NULL)
    {
      p->next=NULL;
      head=p;
      return head;
    }
   else
    {
      while(curr->next!=NULL)
      {
        curr=curr->next;
      }
    curr->next=p;
    p->next=NULL;
   return head;
}
}


struct Queue* Dequeue(struct Queue *head, int *x)
{
   struct Queue *current=head;

   if(head==NULL)
   {
     printf("Queue is empty\n");
   }
  else
   {
    head=head->next;
    *x=current->data;
    free(current);
    return head;
}
}



struct Graph *addelementinlist()
{
  int i,x,y;

  struct Graph *G = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));

  printf("Enter the vertices and Edges : ");
  scanf("%d %d",&G->V,&G->E);

  G->Adj=malloc(sizeof(struct list) * G->V);

  //Read the vertices;
  for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
  {
    G->Adj[i].head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    G->Adj[i].head->verticenum=i;
    G->Adj[i].head->next=NULL;
  }

  //Read the edges
  for(i=0;i<G->E;i++)
  {
    printf("Enter the source and destinatiion : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    struct node *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *temp1=malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    struct node *curr=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    curr=G->Adj[x].head;
    temp->verticenum=y;
    if(curr==NULL)
    {
       temp->next=NULL;
       curr->next=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while(curr->next!=NULL)
         {
             curr=curr->next;
         }
    temp->next=NULL;
    curr->next=temp;
    }

//Incase of undirected other one 
    curr=G->Adj[y].head;
    temp1->verticenum=x;
    if(curr==NULL)
    {
       temp1->next=NULL;
       curr->next=temp1;
    }
    else
    {
        while(curr->next!=NULL)
         {
             curr=curr->next;
         }
    temp1->next=NULL;
    curr->next=temp1;
    }
  }

 return G;
}


void bfs(struct Graph *G, int v)
{
  int visited[MAX],u,a,w;

  visited[v]=1;
  u=v;

  printf("Visit u\t%d\n",u); 
  struct Queue *Q = malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
  Q = Enqueue(Q,u);

  while(Q!=NULL)
  {

   Q = Dequeue(Q,&u);
   printf("Vertice u : %d\n",u);
   struct node *current=G->Adj[u].head;
   while(current!=NULL)
   {
     current=current->next;
     printf("current->verticenum : %d\n",current->verticenum);
     w=current->verticenum;
     Q = Enqueue(Q,w);
     printf("Adjascent vertices w : %d\n",w);
     if(visited[w]==0)
      {
        visited[w]=1;
      }
   }

  }
}

void bft(struct Graph *G)
{
  int visited[MAX],i;
  for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
   {
      visited[i]=0;
   }
  for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
  {
     if(visited[i]==0)
      {
        bfs(G,i);
      }
  }
}


void printgraph(struct Graph *G)
{
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
  {
     struct node *temp = G->Adj[i].head;
      while(temp!=NULL)
       {
          printf("%d",temp->verticenum);
          temp=temp->next;
          printf("->");
       }
    printf("NULL\n");
  }
}

int main()
{
  struct Graph *p = addelementinlist();
  bft(p);
  printgraph(p);
}
```

---

```
Example 1(output):
Enter the vertices and Edges : 4 3
Enter the source and destinatiion : 0 1
Enter the source and destinatiion : 1 2
Enter the source and destinatiion : 2 3
Visit u 0
Vertice u : 0
current->verticenum : 1
Adjascent vertices w : 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)



Enter the vertices and Edges : 4 3
Enter the source and destinatiion : 0 1
Enter the source and destinatiion : 0 2
Enter the source and destinatiion : 1 2
Visit u 0
Vertice u : 0
current->verticenum : 1
Adjascent vertices w : 1
current->verticenum : 2
Adjascent vertices w : 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

well the answer is resolved thank you all for the help.

Comment: using a debugger is particularly efficient in those cases. Try it, after that you won't be able to work without it.

Comment: printf("current->verticenum : %d\n",current->verticenum); 
 w=current->verticenum;

this is the exact place where i am getting seg fault.. i am not sure whether i am wrongly accessing or something....

Comment: the only thing that can go wrong in this line is the access of an element pointed by an address. Check that address.

Comment: yaa the address is showing null.
162      printf("current->verticenum : %d\n",current->verticenum);
(gdb) p current->verticenum
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) p &current->verticenum
$1 = (int *) 0x0

but i dont know how to fix this...

Comment: the answer below explains why you're getting NULL

Comment: yup done that but the graph is now going in infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

This part may lead to a segfault:

```
   while(current!=NULL)
   {
     current=current->next;
     printf("current->verticenum : %d\n",current->verticenum);
```

You have tested that `current` is not `NULL` but `current->next` might be.

I believe that the line `current=current->next` should simply be moved at the end of the while loop.

Also, do not forget to test if you've already visited a node. This could create an infinite loop if the graph is cyclic.

Comment: yaa this the one showing segmentation fault
printf("current->verticenum : %d\n",current->verticenum);

Comment: Am I answering your question or do you need more help? I believe that the line `current=current->next` should simply be moved at the end of the while loop but I haven't tested.